# calculating average of difference between numbers using linq

Tags: linq, dataview, date-arithmetic

I have a column which has double values.
I have to calculate the average of the difference between each values upon all the values in the column.

for example:
for 1, 2, 3.5
the average is: ( (2-1) + (3.5-2) ) / 2

Is there a linq way to do it or another smart way?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) and [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) together to create the "difference between adjacent numbers" part, and then the normal average:

```
var differenceAverage = input.Zip(input.Skip(1), (x, y) => y - x).Average();
```

This relies upon the ability to read `input` twice (and get the same results each time) however - hopefully that's not a problem in your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The values are in a dataview which I want to split the dataview to groups of days. for example, all the values from 1/1/2001 will be at the same group, all the values from the 2/1/2001 will be at the same group. than I want to make the solution you posted and then I want to make the avarage between avarage of every group. any smart way ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you've got the values in an array (or list, or any other similar collection), you can do something like this:

```
double[] values = new[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.5 };
var averageDifference = Enumerable
    .Range(0, values.Length - 1)
    .Select(i => values[i + 1] - values[i])
    .Average();
```

If the values are not in an array-like collection, you could go with Jon Skeet's answer. Alternatively, you might like to create your own extension method; Something like this should work:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectAdjacentPairs<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    Func<TSource, TSource, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            TSource prev = enumerator.Current;
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return resultSelector(prev, enumerator.Current);
                prev = enumerator.Current;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like:

```
var averageDifference = values.SelectAdjacentPairs((x, y) => y - x).Average();
```

This method won't require per-index access of items like using my first method, or enumerating your set twice like using `Zip`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The values are in a dataview which I want to split the dataview to groups of days. for example, all the values from 1/1/2001 will be at the same group, all the values from the 2/1/2001 will be at the same group. than I want to make the solution you posted and then I want to make the avarage between avarage of every group. any smart way ? Thanks

Comment: @user1902346 I've provided an alternate solution, which might help you, but in case you're still stuck, could you show your query so far?